# Trouble writing a program that counts strings in a line in a file

Tags: python

I have several tasks for my course regarding Python. I am stuck where to begin.

Essentially, they boil down to writing various programs that print the username with the highest count of followers, with ties printing all usernames with the same count in alphanumerical order. The dummy-file in question is named `follows.txt` and contains the following:

```
andrew fred
fred
judy andrew fred
george judy andrew
john george
```

Each line begins with the username and then each name after is the name of who they follow. The main file, however is a lot larger and contains nonalphanumeric characters.

EDIT: What would I need to write to bring back the username with the highest count that can also be used on usernames containing characters such as `#`?

I attempted several methods, but met several errors when it came to finding the right way to code what I was attempting to write.

```
user = list()
count = ()
maxCount = ()
follows = ['andrew fred', 'fred', 'judy andrew fred', 'george judy andrew',
           'john george']
```

along with:

```
with open('follows.txt', 'r') as follows:
    for line in follows:
        for word in line:
            count += 1
            word += 1
            if count > maxCount:
                maxCount == count
                count == 0
                user.append(line(0))
            elif count == maxCount:
                user.append(line(0))
```

With the above code, the program I was using wasn't able to open the text file and so I turned it into something that the program would be able to read, but the code turned into a comment is what I thought should work. This is where I was able to get to.

Comment: This seems like multiple questions. Try asking one at a time.

Comment: Sorry, I mean to ask what would I write to be able to bring up the username with the highest count that allows for symbols such as '#' in the username.

Comment: @BenjaminHambly Welcome to Stackoverflow. Unfortunately, or fortunately, we do not just give away answers. Please show us your attempt, we'll be glad to help after that.

Comment: @OlivierMelançon Sorry about that, I'll edit that into the main part.

Comment: The meaning of the part about "be used on usernames containing characters such as `#`" is unclear to me.

Comment: The number of whitespace delimited "words" in a line from the file—including the first word—is simply `len(line.split())`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `len()`, `readlines()`, and `split()` functions as well as list comprehensions as mentioned in the other answers. In addition to this, you can use a dict comprehension to hold the data in a more meaningful way.

```
In [1]: with open('follows.txt', 'r') as f:
    ...:     follows = {p[0]: len(p) - 1 for p in [user.split() for user in f.read().splitlines()]}
    ...:

In [2]: follows
Out[2]: {'andrew': 1, 'fred': 0, 'george': 2, 'john': 1, 'judy': 2}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can `open` the file, and for each line, `.split()` it into a list of words, like.

```
with open('follows.txt') as follows:
    data = [line.split() for line in follows]
```

This gives you a list of lines where each line is a list of words. This would be a good starting point.

Note that this is assuming `follows.txt` is in your working directory (usually wherever you launched `python` from. Try passing the full path to `open()` if that doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few hints:

- Strings in Python have a method called `split()` that divides the string into a list of strings. If you pass it no argument, it assumes you're splitting by whitespace:

  ```
  >>> 'judy andrew fred'.split()
  ['judy', 'andrew', 'fred']
  ```
- Python's built-in `len()` function tells you how many elements any object has. In the case of lists, it works as you might expect:

  ```
  >>> len(['judy', 'andrew', 'fred'])
  3
  ```
- When you read a file in Python, it's most common to do it line-by-line:

  ```
  >>> with open('file.txt') as file:
  ...     for line in file:
  ...         print(line)
  andrew fred
  fred
  judy andrew fred
  george judy andrew
  john george
  ```

You won't have to worry about characters like `#`, because the `split()` method doesn't differentiate between `#` and any alphanumeric character.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way I can think of would be to determine the line with the most words in it and subtract `1` from that to get the number of followers. Note this may not handle "ties" the way you want (but you never mentioned what to do in that scenario).

```
with open('follows.txt', 'r') as follows:
    mostWords = max(follows, key=lambda line: len(line.split()))

maxCount = len(mostWords.split()) - 1

print(maxCount)  # -> 2
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to include first word in each line for followers count and return the list of users with maximum followers. Therefore, use partition first and then split. Calculate maximum frequency and return appropriate values.

```
with open('follows.txt') as f:
    content = f.readlines()
content = [x.strip() for x in content]
foll_list = []
for i in content:
    follow = (i.partition(' ')[2]).split()
    foll_list.extend(follow)
foll_count = {x:foll_list.count(x) for x in foll_list}
print("maximum following count: ", [key for key,val in foll_count.items() if val == max(foll_count.values())])
```